# Could not get unknown property 'enableHermes' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

Tags: react-native, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I need to run on my android an app that I'm producing through "yarn android" but when I try to get an error, and when opening the android folder of my app in android-studio, this error appears.

Answer (score 11):

Just add `hermesEnabled=true` in your gradle.properties file

Answer (score 5):

Findout where is the variable named *enableHermes* being called. Usually the DefaultDependencyHandler is inside your build.gradle.

Open your **build.gradle** file inside **/app** folder.
Check if there is any *enableHermes* variable defined. If not add the following line

```
project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: <Your needed value>
]
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", <Your needed value>);
```

Comment: Fixed the issue for me :)

Answer (score 5):

Add the hermesEnabled=true or hermesEnabled=false in your gradle.properties file.

Tested on React Native >= 0.71.8

Comment: this worked, but why? app/build.gradle already had this property